# Mp3 compressor with 8Kbps

Tags: mp3

May you please recommend me a software to compress Mp3 file at 8Kbps rate? I searched a lot and the lowest bit rate I foud was 32Kbps

Comment: What OS should it run on? What is your price margin if it comes to paid solutions?

Answer (score 2):

ffmpeg can do the conversion. Follow the below command.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 8k output.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

LAME can do this. Here is a program using LAME that includes the option for 8Kbps. https://www.freac.org/